# Nesting Regex within Option match

Tags: scala

I have code which checks to see if a JSON object has a valid date field. I realize that I could have a Some(s) case and then nest another "match" within that function, but I am wondering if there is a more concise way to do this within the top level "match". This is the code I tried, but will not return a "success". I assume there is a way to accomplish this because so many people talk about how robust the scala pattern matching is. Thanks!

```
val p = """(\d\d\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d)""".r

(json \ "date").validate[String].asOpt match {
    case Some(p(date)) => Json.obj("success"->date)
    case None => Json.obj("error"->"missing date")
    case _ => Json.obj("error"->"invalid date")
}
```

Comment: Don't forget about bounded closures (what the JavaDoc calls “quantifiers”). You could write your RE like this: `"""(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}"""`. You can have lower bounds with `{min,}` and upper bounds with `{,max}` and both with `{min,max}`.

Comment: About conciseness, you could find useful Acolyte scalac plugin, to declare the regex only where you use it (in case of pattern matching, without having to declare the val as stable identifier): https://github.com/cchantep/acolyte/blob/master/scalac-plugin/readme.md

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write it like so:

```
val p = """(\d\d\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d)""".r
Option("2014-08-07") match {
  case Some(p(year,month,day)) => println("Yay")
  case None => println("Boo")
}
```

but it's really better to do the two-step thing if there's any way to get a non-string in there.  In particular, if you don't know it's an `Option[String]` but just an `Any`, figuring out that it's a string is an important separate step.  You can write an extractor for it:

```
object IsString {
  def unapply(a: Any): Option[String] = a match {
    case s: String => Some(s)
    case _ => None
  }
}
// Then Some(IsString(p(y,m,d)))
```

If you don't need to validate the three groups that you match, `p(_*)` will just test for the presence of the pattern.

(Thanks to som-snytt for fixing a misconception that somehow has been lingering in my head for years.)

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I'm looking for. I'll be sure to check that the month/days are valid in some later logic. Thanks!

Comment: Both the details are incorrect. For yes/no match, ignoring groups, use `p(_*)` http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.2/index.html#scala.util.matching.Regex@unapplySeq(c:Char):Option[List[Char]]

Comment: @som-snytt - Oops.  Indeed.